# Camera setting does not give the expected fisheye result

Tags: rendering, camera, blender-internal-render-engine

I am modeling a real camera with a wide angle (fisheye). My room is 4*4*2.5 meters and the camera is attached in the ceiling with {0,0,0} degrees rotations. For camera setting, I added a camera named prosilica having a sensor type 2/3" (8.8mm*6.6mm). as mentioned in the image 1 and 2.
When I render the scene, i remark:
1) It does not a distortion effect! Normally, we get a distortion caused by the wide lens of camera (large filed of view)?

How can I simulate a fisheye on blender using the same sensor size mentioned above? Any suggestions?

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: render]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The blender internal renderer doesn't seem to support fisheye lenses. The Cycles rendering engine does, however. You can change to Cycles rendering in the header of the 3D view:

[image]

With Cycles selected you can change your camera type to 'Panoramic' to reveal several fish eye options:

[image]

Comment: I always wondered why the Panoramic option was visible in BI.. Do you happen to know?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the configuration as you proposed but when I render, i get a black image. I did not change the light position. So what is the problem?

Comment: @startingBlender I'm afraid I couldn't say, other than Blender Internal materials are incompatible with Cycles and will have to be rebuilt.

Comment: @gandalf3 I only know what the docs say: "Panoramic renders the scene with a cylindrical projection".